# Halide for tile metric and scheduling on GPU

Tags: c++, image-processing, halide

I'm trying to implement a metric working on squared tiles (8x8) of a gray scale image producing 3 outputs (accumulation of gradient, max and min of a tile): each output is an image having a dimension of (IMG_WIDTH/8; IMG_HEIGHT/8). In the following implementation the 3 results are computed separately but I'd like to compute them all together; moreover I cannot find a good schedule for gpu:

```
#define IMAGE_WIDTH     (1280)
#define IMAGE_HEIGHT    (1024)
#define TILE_SIZE       (8)

    Halide::Buffer<uint8_t> input_image(IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT);

    Halide::Var xo, yo, xi, yi;

    Halide::Func tiled_input;
    tiled_input(xi, yi, xo, yo) = input_image(Halide::clamp(xo * TILE_SIZE + xi, 0, input_image.width()-1),
                                              Halide::clamp(yo * TILE_SIZE + yi, 0, input_image.height()-1));


    Halide::Expr gradientX, gradientY;
    gradientX = Halide::cast<int16_t>(tiled_input(xi+1, yi, xo, yo)) - Halide::cast<int16_t>(tiled_input(xi-1, yi, xo, yo));
    gradientY = -(Halide::cast<int16_t>(tiled_input(xi, yi+1, xo, yo)) - Halide::cast<int16_t>(tiled_input(xi, yi-1, xo, yo)));

    Halide::Expr agx, agy, m;
    agx = Halide::abs(gradientX);
    agy = Halide::abs(gradientY);
    m = Halide::select(agx > agy, agx+(agy/2), agy+(agx/2));


    Halide::RDom tile_domain(0, TILE_SIZE, 0, TILE_SIZE);
    Halide::Func tiled_output_x, tiled_output_y;
    tiled_output_x(xi, yi, xo, yo) = Halide::cast<int16_t>(m);



    Halide::Func  accx;
    Halide::Func tiled_output_max, tiled_output_min;

    accx(xo, yo) = Halide::sum(tiled_output_x(tile_domain.x, tile_domain.y, xo, yo));
    tiled_output_max(xo, yo) = Halide::maximum(tiled_input(tile_domain.x, tile_domain.y, xo, yo));
    tiled_output_min(xo, yo) = Halide::minimum(tiled_input(tile_domain.x, tile_domain.y, xo, yo));

    Halide::Buffer<int16_t> output_buffer_accx(input_image.width()/TILE_SIZE, input_image.height()/TILE_SIZE);
    Halide::Buffer<uint8_t> output_buffer_max(input_image.width()/TILE_SIZE, input_image.height()/TILE_SIZE);
    Halide::Buffer<uint8_t> output_buffer_min(input_image.width()/TILE_SIZE, input_image.height()/TILE_SIZE);

    accx.realize(output_buffer_accx, get_host_target());
    tiled_output_max.realize(output_buffer_max, get_host_target());
    tiled_output_min.realize(output_buffer_min, get_host_target());
```

A good schedule for CPU can be the following:

```
    accx.vectorize(xo, TILE_SIZE).parallel(yo);
    tiled_output_max.vectorize(xo, TILE_SIZE).parallel(yo);
    tiled_output_min.vectorize(xo, TILE_SIZE).parallel(yo);
```

But I cannot find the appropriate for GPU.
Any help ?

Comment: I see `select( agx > agx`. Surely you meant to compare with `agy`.

Comment: Try packing the three results into a `Tuple`. This works in this case because the outputs are the same size.

Answer (score 0):

The comment about packing the three results into a Tuple is the simplest way to compute them all together.

Re: a GPU schedule, have you looked at the examples in the `apps` folder? Several of them have well-thought-out complete GPU schedules that should prove useful.

Comment: I've already used the following schedule: accx.gpu_tile(xo, yo, xb, yb, xt, yt, TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE); but it didn't work well